# Qt Controls so small on Android

Tags: android, qt, controls, stylesheet

I'm having problems using Qt Controls such as QScrollBar, QSpinBox, QCheckBox and QTabBar on Qt 5.3.1. The application for Windows is perfect but when I compile it for Android those controls just reduce the size. I'm sure that it's related to the fact of the PPI (pixels per inch) of my Galaxy S4 screen but I don't know how to solve it. I'm using Qt Widgets (no QML) and I tried to use Style Sheets to solve this problem but it isn't a good idea once the size is variable according to the device which my application will be deployed. Has someone a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this in your *main.cpp*:

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling); // <-- This line.

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're on the right track - you absolutely have to take device size and PPI into account when developing for Android. Defining UI element sizes in raw pixels just isn't a viable solution, I'm afraid.

Native Android apps define everything in terms of 'density-independent pixels', which are an imaginary unit that ensures that your UI elements will be the same size on every device. Now, I assume you don't have access to these, so you'll have to roll your own solution, which will be trickier. Perhaps you could simply compute the pixel dimensions of your UI at runtime, in terms of ratios? For instance, instead of saying 'this button is 100px wide', say 'this button takes up 10% of the screen's width'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you don't specify size of controls, then they have platform dependent default size - eg. QML Button looks just like default android button.

However, if you really need to specify size of control, there is way to accomplish that. There is Screen element with property pixelDensity, so if you want to specify size in millimeters, you just have to do something like this:

```
Rectangle {
   width: 50 * Screen.pixelDensity
   height: 20 * Screen.pixelDensity
}
```

And this creates Rectangle with size 50x20mm on every platform. You can even export Screen.PixelDensity from root window like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    property int mm: Screen.pixelDensity
}
```

And then use height: 20 * mm.

Bottom line is, that if you use Qt Quick Controls, its much better to *not* specify size of element and use default size. But if you need scalable element that is not Qt Quick Controls based, the second approach might come handy.